# timestamp não indica a data correta

Tags: php, mysql

Estou a trabalhar num CMS para *display* dos artigos, o meu problema é com a a função `strtotime()` não indica a data correta, indica sempre 01 março de 1970. A  row (phpMyAdmin) de um dos `article_timestamp` é dado com a formatação: ex. `1394220287`. O que estou a fazer mal?

```
<span id="date">Publicado  
<?php
    setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');
    $timeStamp = $article['article_timestamp'];
    $uppercaseMonth = ucfirst(gmstrftime('%B'));
    echo strftime( '%A, %d de ' .$uppercaseMonth. ' de %Y', strtotime($timeStamp));
?></span>
```

Comment: Miguel, podes juntar à pergunta um exemplo de um dos teus `timestamp`(s)? um dos valores que tens na BD

Comment: Já fiz o update, Obrigado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo exemplo que juntaste à pergunta vejo que `$timeStamp` já é uma `timestamp`, então não é preciso o [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/strtotime).

Usa só:

```
echo strftime( '%A, %d de ' .$uppercaseMonth. ' de %Y', $timeStamp);
//                                                     ^^ - tirei o strtotime()
```

[**Exemplo no PHP Fiddle**](http://phpfiddle.org/api/run/nxp-ucz)

Comment: Muito obrigado, resultou

Answer (score 0):

Se o formato da data passada para `strtotime()` não for válido a função retorna `false`. Use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` para converter datas para timestamp:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2014-01-01 12:00:00');
```

Comment: Obrigao, como implentaria isso no meu codigo?

Comment: Já tentei mas está a dar erro

Answer (score 0):

Você pode trazer a data/hora já correta do MySQL usando a função [FROM_UNIXTIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

```
SELECT
  FROM_UNIXTIME(article_timestamp, '%W, %d de %M de %Y %h:%i:%s') 
FROM 
  sua_tabela
```